# How to stop a stack buffer overflow when reading from file?

Tags: c

I'm reading from a `.txt` file to save it to a `char` array at the same size as the file itself. Is this enough to stop a uncontrolled stack buffer overflow from happening?

I already tried to use a fixed size buffer, but I now understand that's the very reason why the overflow is happening.

```
FILE *inputFP = NULL;

inputFP = fopen(input_file, "r");
if (inputFP == NULL)
    return 1;
fseek(inputFP, 0, SEEK_END);
long fileSize = ftell(inputFP);
fseek(inputFP, 0, SEEK_SET);
char buffer[fileSize+20];

while ((ch = fgetc(inputFP)) != EOF) 
{
     buffer[i] = ch;
     i++;
}

fprintf(outputFP, buffer, "%s");
```

Things work just fine, but I worry that the input file can be so big that something bad happens.

Comment: Use `malloc` to allocate the memory. That way the memory comes from the heap (which typically has gigabytes of memory) instead of the stack (which typically has megabytes of memory).

Comment: you need to read file progressively, not as whole. Even if you use `malloc`, you may be in trouble if file is too big(for example a 10 GB file).

Comment: _Things work just fine, but I worry that the inputfile can be so big that something bad happens._ , you are right, a not too big file (e.g. more than 8192 Kbs on linux) can exceed the stack, you can use dynamic memory: `char *buffer = malloc(filesize);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri For binary data the terminator may not be relevant, but for text files used as C strings it is. Hard to say what to do here without knowing more about the nature of the data involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to limit buffer overflow is to carefully control the amount of memory that's written to any buffer.

If you say (in pseudocode):

```
filesize = compute_file_size(filename);
buffer = malloc(filesize);
read_entire_file_into(buffer, filename);
```

then you've got a big, gaping, potential buffer overflow problem.  The fundamental problem is not that you allocated a buffer just exactly matching the size of the file (although that might be a problem).  The problem is not that you computed the file's size in advance (although that might be a problem).  No, the fundamental problem is that in the hypothetical call

```
read_entire_file_into(buffer, filename);
```

you did *not tell the `read_entire_file_into` function how big the buffer was*.  This may have been the `read_entire_file_into` function's problem, not yours, but the bottom line is that functions that write an arbitrary amount of data into a fixed-size buffer, without allowing the size of that buffer to be specified, are disasters waiting to happen.  That's why the notorious `gets()` function has been removed from the C Standard.  That's why the `strcpy` function is disrecommended, and can be used (if at all) only under carefully-controlled circumstances.  That's why the `%s` and `%[...]` format specifiers to `scanf` are disrecommended.

If, on the other hand, your code looks more like this:

```
filesize = compute_file_size(filename);
buffer = malloc(some_random_number);
read_entire_file_into_with_limit(buffer, some_random_number, filename);
```

-- where the point is that the (again hypothetical) `read_entire_file_into_with_limit` function can be told how big the buffer is -- then in this case, even if the `compute_file_size` function gets the wrong answer, and even if you use a completely different size for `buffer`, you've ensured that you won't overflow the buffer.

Moving from hypothetical pseudocode to real, actual code: you didn't show the part of your code that actually read something from the file.  If you're calling `fread` or `fgets` to read the file, and if you're properly passing your `fileSize` variable to these functions as the size of your `buffer`, then you have adequately protected yourself against buffer overflow.  But if, on the other hand, you're calling `gets`, or calling `getc` in a loop and writing characters to `buffer` until you reach `EOF` (but without checking the number of characters read against `fileSize`), then you *do* have a big, potential buffer overflow problem, and you need to rethink your strategy and rewrite your code.

---

There's a secondary issue with your code which is that you are allocating your buffer as a variable-length array (VLA), on the stack (so to speak).  But really big stack-allocated arrays will fail -- not because of buffer overflow, but because they're literally too big.  So if you actually want to read an entire file into memory, you will definitely want to use `malloc`, not a VLA.  (And if you don't mind an operating-system-dependent solution, you might want to look into memory-mapped file techniques, e.g. the `mmap` call.)

---

You've updated your code, so now I can update this answer.  The file-reading loop you've posted is dangerous -- in fact it's exactly what I had in mind when I wrote about

> calling `getc` in a loop and writing characters to buffer until you reach `EOF` (but without checking the number of characters read against `fileSize`)

You should replace that code with either

```
while ((ch = getc(inputFP)) != EOF) 
{
     if(i >= fileSize) {
         fprintf(stderr, "buffer overflow!\n");
         break;
     }

     buffer[i] = ch;
     i++;
}
```

or

```
while ((ch = getc(inputFP)) != EOF && i < fileSize) 
{
     buffer[i] = ch;
     i++;
}
```

---

Or, you can take a completely different approach.  Most of the time, there's no need to read an entire file into memory all at once.  Most of the time, it's perfectly adequate to read the file a line at a time, or a chunk at a time, or even a character at a time, processing and writing out each piece before moving on to the next.  That way, you can work on a file of any size, and you don't need to try to figure out how big the file is in advance, and you don't need to allocate a big buffer, and you don't need to worry about overflowing that buffer.

I don't have time to show you how to do that today, but there are hints and suggestions in some of the other answers.

Comment: I use   while ((ch = fgetc(inputFP)) != EOF)... to write to the buffer[fileSize]. Then I write buffer to a .txt file with fprintf().

Comment: @Richard That looks to me like what I referred to as "calling `getc` in a loop and writing characters to buffer until you reach EOF (but without checking the number of characters read against `fileSize`)", meaning that yes, it is a big fat potential buffer overflow problem.

Comment: yes you are right. How can I check for the number of characters read against fileSize? Should I read like 512 chars into the buffer and then write it to file, repeating until the file reach EOF?

Comment: @Richard Yes: Reading a chunk, processing, writing, and repeating is an excellent and highly recommended technique.

Comment: is there a chance that you can point me in the right direction? For the last 24 hours I used most of my time to find a way to do this in a good way. I'm kind of stuck with it because the next program I am going to make is a program that reads text from stdin into a buffer so I can convert it to hex and display it with stdout. Same problem I have with this program(?) just dealing with stdin instead of a .txt file

Comment: @Richard The basic pattern is `while((x = inputfunc(...)) != EOF) { ... process one chunk ... }`.  The input function can be `getc`, `fgets`, or `fread`.  If the input function is `getc` (or `getchar`), `x` is the one character you're working with during one trip through the loop.  If the input function is `fread`, `x` is a count of the characters in this chunk.  And if the input function is `fgets`, `x` is a pointer to this chunk, which you can call `strlen` on to get its length, and which you'd actually have to compare against `NULL`, not `EOF`, as the loop termination condition.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm reading from a .txt file to save it to an char array at the same size as the file itself. Is this enough to stop a uncontrolled stack buffer overflow from happening?

You prevent *buffer* overflows by avoiding writes outside your array. They are a Very Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup>.

*Stack* overflows occur when you exhaust the available pages assigned for the stack in your thread/process/program. Typically the size of the stack is *very* small (consider it on the order of 1 MiB). These are also Bad, but they will only crash your program.

> ```
> long fileSize = ftell(inputFP);
> ...
> char buffer[fileSize+20];
> ```

That is a Variable Length Array (VLA). It allocates dynamic (not known at compile-time) stack space. If you use it right, you won't have *buffer* overflows but you will have *stack* overflows, since the file size is unbounded.

---

What you should do, instead of using VLAs, is use a fixed-size buffer and read chunks of the file, rather than the entire file. If you really need to have the entire file in memory, you can try to allocate heap memory (`malloc`) for it or perhaps memory map it (`mmap`).

Comment: Okei, thanks @Acorn. The course example asks me to copy a .txt file. So I should be fine using malloc() then? Or should I read like 512 chars into the buffer and then write it to file, repeating in append-mode until the file reach EOF?

Comment: If you just need to copy, you can make it work with chunks of any size. Even 1 byte at a time would work even if slow.

Comment: Okei, thanks! After 10+ hours spent on trying to find a good solution I just found this:

```ssize_t r = 0, i = 0;
do {
  r = read( fd, buffer + i, 1024 ); // try to read 1024 bytes
  i += r; 
} while( r > 0 ); ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, `malloc()` can prevent buffer-overflow in your case.

As a side note, always try to read file progressively and don't load it completely in memory. In case of large files, you will be in trouble because your process will not be able to allocate that amount of memory. For example, it is almost impossible to load a 10GB video file in memory completely. In addition, normally every large file of data is structured so you can read it progressively in small chunks.

Comment: Thank you. I've been working hard to find a solution for the last 24 hours!